# Successfully passed `this` context to an async function but how to retrieve `this` context when it is done NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am able to console log `this` in the context I want as long as I'm in the event listener. But I can't seem to update or change the more global object. How can I return the value to update a more global object?

I've tried to call the functions with bind, I also thought maybe it is an async problem and tried to solve using promises.

```
const { createReadStream } = require("fs");
const { createInterface } = require("readline");

export default class Process {
  constructor() {
      let self = this;
      let file = [];

      let lineReader = createInterface({
        input: createReadStream(this.filePath)
      });

      lineReader
        .on("line", line => {
          file.push(line);
        })
        .on("close", () => {

          self.file = file;
          console.log(self);
          return self;
        });
    }
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Process {
  filePath: 'path/to/file',
  file:
   [ 'line1',
     'line2'
    ] }
```

The actual output is:

```
Process {
  filePath: 'path/to/file' }
```

Comment: Does `console.log(self);` give the expected output? `console.log(this);` runs before the file is read so `file` can't be logged. I think its an async problem too.

Comment: `console.log(self)` results in the same output as `this`. Okay, I can try to work on it as if its async then. Makes sense that event listeners would fire after a straight `console.log` I have been using `return` instead of that last `console.log` but same result either way. I can work on building a `Promise`

Comment: add  `file.push(line);` on `close` too and console.log(this) to check if its working.. you dont self if using with arrow functions

Comment: FWIW async constructor is an antipattern.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions y'all. This is my first time using ES6 exports. I was just using the constructor to minimize code size for the question. But noted in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the `createInterface` method returns a promise making this an async issue. [This guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) helped me implement a `Promise` to solve the issue. Also used this [reference](http://es6-features.org/#PromiseUsage) to help with syntax:

```
const { createReadStream } = require("fs");
const { createInterface } = require("readline");

function processFile(filePath) {
  let data = '';

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    createInterface({
      input: createReadStream(filePath)
    })
    .on("line", line => {
      data += line + '\n';
    })
    .on("close", f => {
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your corrected code in your answer to help others?